# Mock a method in the class under test without PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have `MyClass` with

- public `doSomething` - method to be tested
- protected static `getYourStaticBool` - method to be mocked, contains `System.getenv` method which cannot be mocked
- static boolean `MY_STATIC_BOOL` - it has to be static and the value is provided by `getYourStaticBool`

MyClass:

```
  public class MyClass {

   private static boolean MY_STATIC_BOOL = getYouStaticBool();

   public void doSomething() {
     if (MY_STATIC_BOOL) {
        //....
     }
   }

   protected static boolean getYourStaticBool() {
     return Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("foo"))
         .map(Boolean::parseBoolean)
         .orElse(false);
   }
  }
```

Now I want to `doSomething` so I have to mock `getYourStaticBool` to set `MY_STATIC_BOOL` on true.

```
  @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
  public class MyClassTest {

   private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

   @BeforeAll
   void static init() {
     try (MockedStatic<MyClass> myClass = Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class)) {
       myClass.when(() -> MyClass.getYourStaticBool())
           .thenReturn(true);
     }
   }
  
   @Test
   void shouldDoSth() {
    myClass.doSomething();
   }
  }
```

Unfortunately calling `myClass.doSomething()` reveals that `MY_STATIC_BOOL` is false. So the real `getYourStaticBool` is called, not the mocked one.
Maybe should I use spy and mock static `getYourStaticBool`? I can't use PowerMockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking the method using `mockStatic` will not work in this case, because the moment `Mockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class)` is executed, the class is initialized and the method you would like to mock is called already to initialize the static field. If you wanted to mock the method call, the `try` block would have to be around the tested code (see: [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76575535/3305737)).

Since `MY_STATIC_BOOL` is not `final`, we can simply set its value using reflection (if it was final it would be also possible, yet not that easy, see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/3305737) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150853/3305737)).

I modified the tested code for the sake of the test:

```java
public String doSomething() {
    if (MY_STATIC_BOOL) {
        return "Success";
    }
    return "Failure";
}
```

and here's the test:

```java
@Test
void shouldDoSth() throws Exception {
    var staticField = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("MY_STATIC_BOOL");
    staticField.setAccessible(true);
    staticField.set(null, true);

    var result = myClass.doSomething();

    assertEquals("Success", result);
}
```

To avoid interfering with other tests, resetting the field with the original value would be advised (for example in `@AfterAll` method or using `try-finally` blocks).

---

Another option, which also works if the field is `final` is using [System Stubs library](https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs/blob/main/system-stubs-jupiter/README.md):

```java
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
class MyClassWithSystemStubsTest {

    @SystemStub
    EnvironmentVariables environment;

    @Test
    void theTest() {
        environment.set("foo", "true");
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        var result = myClass.doSomething();

        assertEquals("Success", result);
    }
}
```

Note that the environment should be set before creating the tested class object (`myClass`), because the class (and the static field) is initialized then, so the instance cannot be created as a field in the test for this to work, unless you use:

```java
@SystemStub
static EnvironmentVariables testWideVariables = new EnvironmentVariables("foo", "true");
```

*(see docs in the link above)*

---

You can find both tests described above in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/7188fe397345e35bbe15d6ea44830b28fd8e7785) - all tests pass.